# VS2010 C# ASP.NET App won't hit breakpoints during debugging

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-debugging

I have a solution that consists of a Class Library project and a remote web site.

I start the debugging and the page comes up and if I make changes to the source I can see them  happen on the page that's in the debugger ... but I can have a breakpoint on the first line of the Page_Load and it still won't hit.  Same things goes for any breakpoint in the Class Library's codebase.

I've debugged other applications off this server successfully before ... but have hit a wall with this one.

What am I doing wrong?

Both projects have are .NET Framework 4.

Comment: Are the break points indicated by a full red circle, meaning the code matches the symbols?

Comment: Which navigator are you using ?

Comment: Is the project built in Debug or Release mode?

Comment: @AdamGritt i don't think it matter if its in debug or release mode. I can put it release and i still can use the debugger.

Comment: I can do the same but the breakpoints won't be hit in Release mode unless you have it generating the symbols.

Comment: Yes, they stay active.  I've run into issues with Breakpoints (especially in Class libraries getting disabled based on builds) but this is not that issue.  It's Debug mode, if that matters.

Comment: Don't ask me to explain it ... the only thing I did differently is that the first time around I started with the Class Library, added the remote site and then set the Web site as the Startup project. Should work the same, you'd think ... but I'm not gonna question it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to try a few more things to get this working so I first did a fresh Open >> Web Site ... so that I had a solution with just the remote web site and tried debugging and that worked. So, decided to try living a little dangerously and then added the Class Library project back and tried Debugging again and it worked for both the .aspx.cs files and the .cs ones from the Class Library!

Don't ask me to explain it ... the only thing I did differently is that the first time around I started with the Class Library, added the remote site and then set the Web site as the Startup project. Should work the same, you'd think ... but I'm not gonna question it

Answer (score 1):

If the breakpoint isn't marked as a full red circle, either no symbols have been loaded for the type or the code you're debugging is different to what you have in your editor.

If the latter, you can right click the breakpoint and select allow source to be different... checkbox

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use internet explorer ? if your in an different navigator.. you must attach that navigator processus to the debugger in order to debug.

Comment: Seeing how he set a breakpoint to Page_Load, I assume he's debugging server side code.